# Retrofit enqueue gets dismissed on orientation change

Tags: android, android-asynctask, retrofit, retrofit2, android-orientation

I am trying to upload plain text and image to the api using RetroFit. I want make sure the request continues to execute on orientation change. To do this, I have encapsulated the RetroFit api call inside a Headless fragment. This works fine when I try to upload an image. The request stops and resumes on device rotation. However it just gets cancelled on a text upload.

The only difference between the two uploads is that for image upload I use execute() and for text I use enqueue(). However, if I try to use execute() with the text, it still does not work.

Below is some code :-

UpdateTaskHelper (Headless fragment)

```
public static class UploadTaskHelper extends Fragment
    {
        private UploadAsync uploadTask;
        private ProgressDialog m_loadingp;

        public static UploadTaskHelper newInstance()
        {
            return new UploadTaskHelper();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setRetainInstance(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy()
        {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "[onDestroy]");
            super.onDestroy();

            if (uploadTask != null)
            {
                uploadTask.cancel(true);
            }
        }

        public void startUpload(ActionActivity actionActivity, boolean shouldTakePhoto, boolean isTextNote, String noteContent)
        {
          uploadTask = new UploadAsync(actionActivity, shouldTakePhoto, isText, noteContent);
          uploadTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        }

        private static class UploadAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
        {
            private Bitmap m_bitmap = null;
            private Pair<Boolean, String> m_errorPair;
            private File m_uploadedFile = null;
            private WeakReference<ActionActivity> m_weakActivity;
            private boolean shouldTakePhoto;
            private boolean isTextNote;
            private java.io.File m_capturedImageFile;

            UploadAsync(@NonNull ActionActivity activity, boolean shouldTakePhoto, boolean isTextNote, String textNoteContent)
            {
                this.m_weakActivity = new WeakReference<>(activity);
                this.shouldTakePhoto = shouldTakePhoto;
                this.isTextNote = isTextNote;
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
            {

                try
                {
                    final ActionActivity activity = this.m_weakActivity.get();

                    activity.m_fileAPIWrapper = new FileAPIWrapper(new IHttpEventTracker<File>()
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void getCallProgress(int progress) {}

                        @Override
                        public void onCallFail(@NonNull String cause, @NonNull Throwable t, @Nullable ResponseBody responseBody)
                        {
                            m_errorPair = new Pair<>(true, t.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCallSuccess(@NonNull RealmList<File> models)
                        {
                            m_errorPair = new Pair<>(false, AppConstants.EMPTY_STRING);
                            m_uploadedFile = models.get(0);
                        }
                    });

                    if(!isTextNote)
                    {
                        final java.io.File storageDir = new java.io.File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            .getAbsolutePath() + java.io.File.separator + activity.getPackageName()
                            + java.io.File.separator + "-" + java.io.File.separator);
                        if (!storageDir.exists())
                        {
                            storageDir.mkdirs();
                        }
                        this.m_capturedImageFile = java.io.File.createTempFile("IMG_" + System.currentTimeMillis(), ".jpg", storageDir);

                        final FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(this.m_capturedImageFile);
                        this.m_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, outStream);
                        outStream.flush();
                        outStream.close();

                        final ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        this.m_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);
                        activity.m_fileAPIWrapper.postImage(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), stream.toByteArray()));
                        stream.flush();
                        stream.close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        activity.m_fileAPIWrapper.postTextNote(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/raw"), activity.m_addContentNoteEdit.getText()
                        .toString()));
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    this.m_errorPair = new Pair<>(true, e.toString());
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute()
            {
                super.onPreExecute();

                activity.m_loading.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
            {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            }
        }
}
```

Network calls :-

```
public void postImage(@NonNull RequestBody reqFile) {
    if (m_eventTracker != null) {
        final ResponseToken token = NetworkUtil.getAccessToken();
        if (getService() != null && m_httpOperationWrapper != null && token != null) {
            m_call = getService().postImage(token.getTokenType() + " " + token.getAccessToken(), NetworkUtil.X_VERSION,
                                            "filename=IMG_" + System.currentTimeMillis(), "image/jpeg", reqFile);
            m_httpOperationWrapper.initCall(m_call, this, true);
        } else {
            m_eventTracker.onCallFail(AppConstants.BAD_REQUEST, new Throwable("Something went wrong, Try again later!"), null);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Execute HTTP call to post a  new text note.
 */
public void postTextNote(@NonNull RequestBody requestBody) {
    if (m_eventTracker != null) {
        final ResponseToken token = NetworkUtil.getAccessToken();
        if (getService() != null && m_httpOperationWrapper != null && token != null) {
            m_call = getService().postFile(token.getTokenType() + " " + token.getAccessToken(), NetworkUtil.X_VERSION,
                                           "filename=" + token.getOwnerId() + "_text_note_" + System.currentTimeMillis(), "text/plain",
                                           requestBody);
            m_httpOperationWrapper.initCall(m_call, this);
        } else {
            m_eventTracker.onCallFail(AppConstants.BAD_REQUEST, new Throwable("Something went wrong, Try again later!"), null);
        }
    }
}

public void initCall(@NonNull Call<ContentResponse> call, @NonNull IHttpOperationCallback callback, final boolean isSynchronousCall) {
    m_callback = callback;
    try {
        if (NetworkUtil.isNetworkAvailable()) {
            if (isSynchronousCall) {
                m_executeRequest(call);
            } else {
                m_enqueueRequest(call);
            }
        } else {
            m_callback.onFailure(call, new Throwable(AppConstants.NO_INTERNET), null);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        m_callback.onFailure(call, e.fillInStackTrace(), null);
    }
}

private void m_enqueueRequest(@NonNull Call<ContentResponse> call) {
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ContentResponse>() {

        @SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ContentResponse> call, @NonNull Response<ContentResponse> response) {
            if (m_callback != null) {
                if (!Util.isValidResponse(response)) {
                    String error = "Status: " + response.code() + " " + response.message();
                    m_callback.onFailure(call, new Throwable(
                            response.code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED ? AppConstants.UNAUTHORIZED : error), response.errorBody());
                    return;
                }
                m_callback.onSuccess(call, response.body());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ContentResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            if (m_callback != null) {
                m_callback.onFailure(call, t, null);
            }
        }
    });
}

@WorkerThread
private void m_executeRequest(@NonNull Call<ContentResponse> call) {
    try {
        Response<ContentResponse> response = call.execute();
        if (m_callback != null) {
            if (!Util.isValidResponse(response)) {
                String error = "Status: " + response.code() + " " + response.message();
                m_callback.onFailure(call,
                                     new Throwable(response.code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED ? AppConstants.UNAUTHORIZED : error),
                                     response.errorBody());
                return;
            }
            //noinspection ConstantConditions
            m_callback.onSuccess(call, response.body());
        }
    } catch (IOException | RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (m_callback != null) {
            m_callback.onFailure(call, e.fillInStackTrace(), null);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the same behaviour for the text note? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you use enqueue your request sent async, and the orientation change destroys the activity and cancels your response code scope.
You should consider move the request code into a ViewModel class which is part of the MVVM architecture. The ViewModel would make the request even after orientation change and keep the data inside it, then you could access its data after the activity is re-created.